# tooltip-html-unsafe stopped working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I have a tooltip that displays an `img` - so I used `tooltip-html-unsafe`
When upgrading to Angular 1.3 (or maybe earlier) it stopped working

1. When trying to upgrade to 0.12 (I have 0.10) I get:
   `angular#>=1 <1.3.0 which resolved to 1.2.27 and is required by angular-bootstrap#0.12.0`
   No 1.3 support?
2. Is there an alternative way to put an image on a tooltip assuming this is not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use angular ui bootstrap 0.12 with angular 1.3.4. I cant see why this wouldn't work for you.

If you have a look at the angular ui bootstrap site, there are plunkers available for each feature shown.

A quick plunker shows that this is compatible so im not sure where your problem lies.
    More information is therefore needed.
`See plunker below`

http://plnkr.co/edit/PycBvj2KaxQgkhybTo56?p=preview

Comment: so do you know why when I run bower install angular-bootstrap I'm getting angular#>=1 <1.3.0?

Comment: OK,officially 1.3 is not yet supported. That said however, I haven't experience any issues with it.Others posting on github are in the same position and dont experience issues. see https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2830 I have a resolution to angular 1.3 in my bower.json and wasnt prepared to wait for official compatibility when i experience no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use ... //angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js
For Angular 1.3